# How to see a particular view clearly amongst lots of overlapping UIViews

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

When a view controller (VC) has hordes of views and subviews it becomes very difficult to modify a subview because I can't even see it completely (it is hidden behind some other subview). For example please have a look at current state of one of my VC:[image: view controller having lots of views and subviews in xcode]

I can't see highlighted "Congratulations - UILabel" or its UIView.

Is there a way I can see a specific view clearly (may be at the top of all the other views)?

Generally I drag drop a UIView on a different dummy blank VC, design view completely on that VC with all constraints and finally drag drop it back to my actual VC. This works most of the times but it seems like an inefficient approach to me.
I've observed that seeing overlapping views used to be easier in iOS6 but it is Very difficult in iOS7. Is there any feature in iOS7 Interface Builder that I am missing? Thanks for your precious time.

Update: Would [Spark Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com) help me here? I am newbie to development so don't want to waste my time trying and understanding new plugin if it doesn't help me achieve what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is widely considered one of the weak points of Xcode's new Storyboards feature. They're great for apps that require a large number of simple controllers, but they become difficult to work with when your interfaces get complicated. Most experienced developers use Storyboards in some places and individual controller XIBs in others, depending on what they're building.

Here's how to solve your problem:

**Step 1. Break the View Controller out of your Storyboard into it's own XIB**

- From the File menu, choose New File and choose an Empty XIB file (from the User Interface section). Name it "YourExactVCClassName.xib".
- Go to your Storyboard. Copy the entire View of your View Controller and then delete it.
- Paste the View Controller into your new XIB. Change the class of "File's Owner" to be your View Controller, and set it's "view" property by drawing an outlet from the view to File's Owner.

> When your app runs, it will try to instantiate the view controller
>   from your storyboard. When it realizes there's no view in the
>   storyboard for that controller, it will automatically find the file
>   MyViewController.xib and load it from there.

**Step 2. Organize the contents of your main view into detached views that make sense.**

- In your example above, it looks like you have different views for different states of the game (game over, high score, etc.) Take each of those and remove them from the main view. With your controller in it's own XIB file, you can just drag the view out in to the whitespace around your controller. Each view you drag out becomes a top level object in the XIB file that you can design and see easily. 
  *You're no longer stuck with an iPhone-5-sized workspace.*
- Create IBOutlets for each of your detached, top level views so you can reference them in your controller.
- In `viewDidLoad`, programmatically add each of the separate views to your main view. Note that you may want to set their frames, make some of them invisible, etc. You have to write more code, but it's generally worth it for an easily maintainable XIB.

Comment: Thanks for referencing the Spark Inspector—unfortunately it's only useful for digging through views in apps that are running. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben for taking out time to answer this. Really appreciated.